# encode/replace blob with base64 in php array

Tags: php, json, html, web-services, blob

Iam currently building an HTML5 app which gets its data json encoded from a php webservice.
I also have small images stored in the database and would like to return them as base64 encoded with the json result.

Currently I get all mysql field and return then as json like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `news` ";

$posts = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
  }
}

 header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
```

I have a field called picture.
Now I would like to convert the picture data in the array posts[] with base64 that I can simply return all data with json without another http request just for the picture.

My php skills are not very good but I thought about something like:

```
$posts['picture'] = base64_encode($posts['picture']);
```

But I need to convert every picture to base64, so maybe its better to put it in the while loop:

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($post == 'picture'){
      $post = base64_encode($post);
    }
    $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
  }
```

Can this work? Or is there any other/better method?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, first, mysql_fetch_assoc will return you the entire row (all columns), this means that `$post` will contain each column name, like:

```
$post['column_name_a']

$post['column_name_b']

$post['column_name_c']

....
```

So, you just should do (It doesn't really matter if it is empty):

```
$post['picture'] = base64_encode($post['picture']);
```

then, you could add it to $posts[] array and then json_encode() it to print.

As a side note, mysql_fetch_assoc is deprecated from PHP 5.5 and will be removed in the future -- see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's not a good idea to store pictures (or any binary data) in database. The classic way is to store the location of the picture.
If you prefer having the picture stored in your database for any reasons, you can do something like what you're doing.

By the way, you can directly have pictures encoded in base64 when you insert it in the database, that would avoid reconverting it each time you want to access one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! 
And you are right... I should consider to change my code in the future.

For now and just for a couple of small images this is working for me:

```
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $post['picture'] = base64_encode($post['picture']);
    $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
  }
```